# FEDEX Web Services - information on data required

Tags: php, web-services, api, fedex

I  have set up a developer test account with FedEx using the PHP code examples provided by FedEx.  I have the following error back from the API:

> "All specified account numbers must match" - code 873

I cannot find what this is caused by, the only thing I think may be causing the issue is I have an empty vairable for `$dutyaccount` but I have not been supplied with any duty account number and have no instructions as to what this is.

```
if($var == 'check') Return true;
//main variables needed to be passes
if($var == 'key') Return 'x8Qffhfhfhfuujj0gI6XW';
if($var == 'password') Return 'dGDJghghwi2BfKa2xdvgHU1245B';    

if($var == 'shipaccount') Return '519987020';
if($var == 'meter') Return '118551669';
if($var == 'billaccount') Return '519951408';
if($var == 'dutyaccount') Return ''; // what is this??
```

However, if I comment out the `dutyaccount` I still get the same error message so perhaps this isnt even needed.  I cannot find specific information on variables needed to be passed to the API to bring back rates.  Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3):

shipaccount and billaccount don't match which could cause that error. you should be billing to the shipper.

Answer (score 0):

```
if($var == 'shipaccount') Return 'XXX'; / your account
if($var == 'billaccount') Return 'XXX'; / who pays shipment charges
if($var == 'dutyaccount') Return 'XXX'; / who pays duties charges
```

but, dutyaccount could be empty because by default recipient pay duties when is delivered the shipment. if you want to define who pays the duties or transportation charges you must define that information in your request: ex:

```
'DutiesPayment' => array(
    'PaymentType' => 'SENDER', // valid values RECIPIENT, SENDER and THIRD_PARTY
    'Payor' => array(
    'ResponsibleParty' => array(
        'AccountNumber' => getProperty('dutyaccount'),
        'Contact' => null,
        'Address' => array('CountryCode' => 'US')
        )
    )
),
```

where the most important part is -> 'PaymentType' => 'SENDER', // valid values RECIPIENT, SENDER and THIRD_PARTY